# How to create a method to be called each time in React

Tags: reactjs, promise

I am quite new to React and want to create a const method like this:

```
async function RunTest() {
  <some logic here> 
  return <a value here> } export const myMethod = RunTest();
```

and then import it in a service and use it like:

```
export async function getValue() {
  const myClient = await myMethod;
  <some logic here>
  return res.data; }
```

The thing is, the method RunTest will be called once when initializing. However, what I want is the content to be run each time when method GetValue in the service is called.

Any suggestions to change the myMethod without changing anything in the service as I have many of those services and don't want to change all of them. If no other way, then I have to go to every single service and change it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's running because you are putting parenthesis at the end of RunTest when exporting it. If you want to rename the export, use the as keyword in the import.

RunTest file

```
export async function RunTest() {
  <some logic here> 
  return <a value here> 
}
```

getValue file:

```
import {RunTest as MyMethod} from "file-path"
export async function getValue() {
  const myClient = await myMethod();
  <some logic here>
  return res.data; }
```

Comment: ahhh what a mistake - thanks mate.